# taghelpers Intellisense missing with in beta 5 Asp.net 5 MVC 6

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, tag-helpers

In beta 5 the intellisense in VS2015 doesn't work for taghelpers.
I fixed the missing attribute error message with adding this stub to my project

How can I fix this?

```
using System;

namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Specifies that a property or parameter value should be initialized via the dependency injection
    /// container for activated types.
    /// </summary>
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public sealed class ActivateAttribute : Attribute
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Found IT. I used beta 6 for a moment. But forgot to rename _ViewImports to _GlobalImport

Comment: I'm confused. In beta5 it must be named _ViewImports.cshtml. I mention this because I am using beta5 and I cannot get intellisense on taghelpers either. If renaming _ViewImports.cshtml back to _GlobalImport.cshtml fixes the intellisense I'm guessing it is a tooling issue where VS still expects _GlobalImport.cshtml, but in beta5 you would get other errors if _ViewImports.cshtml does not exist.

Comment: also your stub seems like a hack vs a [breaking change](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/28) where ActivateAttribute was removed and you are trying to fake it to still be there